# upgrading neovim

Tags: 14.04, vim, neovim

Can't seem to upgrade neovim.

I added the new repo: `add-apt-repository ppa:neovim-ppa/unstable`

And upgraded, but I'm still on nvim 0.1.5-dev, and opening up nvim doesn't pay attention to the .nvimrc file.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't that already the latest version? `0.1.5-dev` is already the nightly build according to https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/tag/nightly.

Comment: Ah, okay, then I'm having weird problems. Super slow to open files. Doesn't respect .nvimrc file unless I use `nvim -u .nvimrc` and also doesn't use xoria256 color file.

Comment: @Costa The default `rc` file is `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`

Comment: That's a little confusing. Is there a resource I can look at with how to set up configuration? Where to put which files from my .vim directory and my .vimrc file?

Comment: Have a look at https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim